# How do the climbing rules work in Numenera?

Tags: movement, numenera

On p. 120 of *Numenera Discover*, the climbing rules say:

> Climbing is like moving through difficult terrain: the move roll is hindered and movement is at half speed.

The rules reference movement in difficult terrain as described on p. 117:

> Difficult terrain hinders move rolls and halves movement on a round-by-round basis.

The climbing rules also include a table of sample difficulties given various surfaces:

| Difficulty | Surface |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Surface with lots of handholds |
| 3 | Stone wall or similar surface |
| 4 | Crumbling or slippery surface |
| 5 | Smooth stone wall or similar surface |
| 6 | Metal wall or similar surface |
| 8 | Smooth, horizontal surface |
| 10 | Glass wall or similar surface |

I'm confused what the rules mean when they say

> the move roll is hindered

and have a few related questions:

1. Does that mean that the task difficulty is hindered, i.e., when the table says that a surface with a lot of handholds is difficult 2, it is really difficulty 3? (In which case, why not just adjust the table to take hindrance into account?)
2. Does that mean that the *move roll*, which can be a difficulty task of 0 (if moving a short distance) or a Speed task difficulty of 4 (if moving a long distance) is hindered, *and* the player must also make a roll of the difficulty shown in the table to climb (i.e., two rolls)?

   1. If #2 is the case, I imagine that move rolls only apply inside of combat (or a similar encounter), so in other cases, such as simply having to climb a cliff, would the player then *only* make a single climb check to climb as much as they want or need to?